# Representability of blow-up of stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, blow-ups

Suppose $\mathcal{Z}\subseteq\mathcal{X}$ is a closed immersion of stacks. Is the blow-up morphism $p:Bl_{\mathcal{Z}}(\mathcal{X})\to\mathcal{X}$ representable? More precisely, if $C\to\mathcal{X}$ is a map from a scheme $C$, what is the fibre product $C\times_{\mathcal{X}}Bl_{\mathcal{Z}}(\mathcal{X})$? Is that something like total transform of $C$?

Comment: The blowing up is the (relative) Proj of a graded sheaf of quasi-coherent algebras.  Since relative Proj is compatible with arbitrary base change, the blowing up is representable by morphisms of schemes.